# Which brewing method extracts more flavors from the coffee bean?

Tags: coffee

Which method extracts more flavors from the bean: espresso, french press/cafetiere, or another method?

And, if I want to try different beans from different countries etc, is a french press/cafetiere the best coffee maker for this?, since a bean of any place or any roast can be brewed in it?

Comment: All methods are valid. What constitutes "flavour" and "more flavour" is personal preference

Comment: As one answer suggests, different brewing methods extract *different* flavours, not necessarily *more* or *less*. Next time you drink coffee, start thinking more about which flavours you like (within a single cup) and which you don't. [Here's a list of common flavour categories](http://www.talkaboutcoffee.com/a-coffee-tasters-glossary.html) and [here's a longer but more subjective list](http://www.zecuppa.com/coffeeterms-cupping-tasting.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More is not always better. To extract the most flavour, just let it simmer for a long time... it just won't be a nice cup of coffee, because that way some unwanted flavours are also extracted.

To make a good cup of coffee, the water, the coffee, the temperature (also of the cup itself), the time, the grind and the blend all are important. Just as important as the method.

Favourite methods are the French press and the espresso machine, but a radical different method is Turkish' coffee, where they take the coffee to a boil three times and serve it without filtering... and it's delicious.

Comment: As a coffee geek, I'll state that I have rarely had good Turkish coffee (about 10% of the time). Of the methods you mentioned, it is the only one I dislike.

Comment: @RickG, I don't usually drink Turkish coffee, so I've been lucky :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point a [macchinetta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_pot) (a.k.a. caffettiera or moka pot) provides a relatively high quality extraction yielding a rich and tasteful cup of coffee.